# Find the 200th number that is divisible by 3 or 4

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

My lecturer gave to me this question

$Q)$ Let the set $A = \mathbb N \setminus$ $ (\{3k \mid k \in \mathbb{N} \}$ $\cup$  $\{4k \mid k \in \mathbb{N} \})$

Say the element $a_1(=1) < a_2(=2) < a_3(=5) <...$ for $a_i \in  \mathbb{N}$ (I.e. $a_n < a_{n+1}$)

Find the number of the $a_{200}$

---

Here is my solution.

As I've known the $[\frac n p]$ is the number of the $p$-multiples which is not larger than $n$ in $\mathbb N$

Since the $\vert \{n(\in \mathbb N) \vert n \leq a_{200} \} \vert =200$, all I have to do just find the $n$ satisfying  $200  = n - [\frac n 3 ] - [\frac n 4] + [\frac n {12}]$ by inclusion–exclusion principle.

But the problem is there isn't only $n$ satisfying $200  = n - [\frac n 3 ] - [\frac n 4] + [\frac n {12}]$ When I check those, $n$ can be there are $398, 400$.

Actually the answer was $398$. Why does the $400$ can't be answer?

Which point did I have in my solution?

Any correct solution and explanation always welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Because $400$ is a multiple of $4$, which cannot belong to $A$. Similarly $200=399-133-99+33$ but $399$ is a multiple of $3$.

Comment: The title asks for the $200$th number that *is* divisible by $3$ or $4$, but the set $A$ consists of numbers that are *not* divisible by $3$ or $4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

399 is a multiple of 3 and 400 a multiple of 4.  Both 398 and 400 have 200 terms below or equal, but only 398 is a term in the sequence.

Comment: Yes it does. I found my mistake.